# PostgreSQL Change Column Name To Another Tables Column

Tags: database, postgresql, select, join

I'm using PostgreSQL.

I have a table for a customers booking, `Folio`, that shows the staff ID of the staff that created the booking, and the ID of the most recent staff to change this booking.

I want to be able to, instead of showing these ID's, change them to show the name of the staff from my `Staff` table.

The fields in these tables are:

```
FOLIO:
CREATE_STAFF_ID, CHANGE_STAFF_ID

STAFF:
STAFF_ID, NAME
```

I've been trying something like:

```
SELECT (c.fields), p.CREATE_STAFF_ID, p.CHANGE_STAFF_ID, s.NAME
FROM OTHERTABLE c
JOIN FOLIO p ON (JOINING OTHERTABLE TO FOLIO TABLE)
JOIN STAFF s ON (p.CREATE_STAFF_ID = s.ALL_STAFF_ID)
WHERE (FILTERING);
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of what you're getting now, and what you would like to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I'm getting what you mean it should show you the ID's and the NAMES for each ID:

```
SELECT f.create_staff_id AS staff_that_created_id
      ,a.name            AS staff_that_created_name
      ,f.change_staff_id AS staff_to_change_id
      ,b.name            AS staff_to_change_name
FROM folio f
LEFT JOIN staff a ON f.create_staff_id = a.staff_id
LEFT JOIN staff b ON f.change_staff_id = b.staff_id
```